# Which episode of Sailor Moon is this scene from?

Tags: sailor-moon

Which episode of the classic Sailor Moon anime are these screenshots of Usagi (Sailor Moon) and Mamoru (Tuxedo Kamen) from?

[image: Usagi close-up]
[image: Usagi with head on Mamoru's lap]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's from the [***Sailor Moon R***](http://anidb.net/perl-bin/animedb.pl?show=anime&aid=2152) movie.

[image]

> The fragrance of a flower at the botanical gardens reminds Mamoru of a
>   long forgotten memory from his childhood when he met Fiore, an alien
>   boy who was travelling the galaxy on his own. Before Fiore left, he
>   made a promise to Mamoru to bring him flowers.
>
> Once banned from society to a far away galaxy, the Kisenian flower, a
>   plant that grows by consuming the energy of living beings, awaits to
>   be found by someone with doubtful heart and weak will on whom to prey,
>   since it is harmless without a proper host — to then transform the
>   host's weakness and fear into dark power.
>
> What will happen when lonely Fiore finds Kisenian during his journey?
>   How will he react to finding out about the passionate relationship
>   between Mamoru and Usagi? Will Sailor Moon be able to save Earth and
>   the ones she loves from Fiore's jealousy powered by the accumulated
>   hatred of the Kisenian against people?

[*YouTube link of that particular scene*](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wiGc5VLTg9M&t=11m54s)